# Vue: Is it possible to set data variables in custom directives

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

I have **SceneList** and **SceneCard** components. I am setting **SceneCard's** bg-color randomly in SceneList. And I want to pass the color code to **SceneCard**. But I am getting: *Error in directive rainbow bind hook: "TypeError: Cannot set property 'bgcolor' of undefined"*. Could someone give the way how to properly set data in custom directives?

Here is my code:

SceneList:

```
<template>
  <div id="scene-list">
    <scene-card
      class="scene-card-comp"
      v-for="scene in scenes"
      :key="scene.id"
      :bgcolor="bgcolor"
      v-rainbow>

    </scene-card>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import SceneCard from './SceneCard.vue';
export default {
  props: ['scenes'],

  components: {
    SceneCard
  },

  data() {
    return {
      bgcolor: null
    };
  },

  directives: {
    rainbow: {
      bind(el, /* binding, vnode */) {
        const bgColor = `#${Math.random().toString().slice(2, 8)}`;
        el.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
        this.bgcolor = bgColor;
        el.style.opacity = '0.5';
      }
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style lang="less">
...
</style>
```

SceneCard:

```
<template>
  <div id="scene-card" @click="changeBGColor">

  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  props: ['bgcolor'],

  data() {
    return {

    };
  },

  methods: {
    changeBGColor() {
      console.log('bgcolor change ', this.bgcolor);
    }
  },
};
</script>
```

Comment: Not an expert of custom directives, but I don't think `this.bgcolor` inside the `bind()` refers to the component.

Answer (score 1):

You can change the properties of your component with `el`, if you use `this` you don't refers to the component.

`el` refers the HTML DOM and the component according to the doc (https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/custom-directive.html)

```
    rainbow: {
        bind(el, /* binding, vnode */) {
            const bgColor =`#${Math.random().toString().slice(2, 8)}`;
            el.style.backgroundColor = bgColor;
            el.bgcolor = bgColor;
            el.style.opacity = '0.5';
           }
        }
```